# Validate the form input in a Laravel request when the input is posted inside an array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, request

I post my input in an array like this:

```
<input class="form-control" id="first_name" name="main_user[first_name]" type="text">
```

And I want to use the Laravel Requests to validate this input. Usually you determine the validation rules like this in a Request file:

```
return ['first_name' => 'required']
```

But this won't work because first_name is posted inside an array. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
return ['main_user[first_name]' => 'required']
```

Comment: Use Form Requests and create dynamic rules for your arrays

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` character when validating array. An example:

```
'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: This just took every value of the array and took the email/first_name from that array. It created rules like this: 
main_user.first_name.first_name => 'required',
main_user.last_name.first_name => 'required', etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was just thinking to hard with the []. I should have used dots like this:

```
return [
    'main_user.first_name' => 'required',
]
```

and

```
return [
    'main_user.first_name.required' => 'Je moet een voornaam invullen 
     voor het beheerders account.',
]
```